# My bootstrap template navbar in collapse mode isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

Please can someone help me, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have tried all the fixes here but still cant seem to fix my nav bar. The links in the nav bar in responsive view are not clickable. I used a tutorial on w3 schools so not sure what's causing it. Also the text in the nav bar isn't formatted correctly. Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Code below:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

    <div class="culmn">
        <!--Home page style-->


        <nav class="navbar navbar-default bootsnav navbar-fixed" role="navigation">

         <div class="navbar-top bg-grey fix">                   
             <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="navbar-callus text-left sm-text-center">
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li><a href="tel:0878209100"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call us: 087 820 9100</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="mailto:sales@urs.co.za"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact us: sales@urs.co.za</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>





                <!-- Start Header Navigation -->
                <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-header" role=navigation>
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NavBarMenu">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                  <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/URS-Logo.png" alt="" width="150" class="logo"></a>


                </div>
                <!-- End Header Navigation -->

                <!-- navbar menu -->
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="NavBarMenu">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                  
                        <li><a href="About.html">Our Story</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="Solutions.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Solutions</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
     <li><a href="Solutions.html#BI">Retail Software</a></li>
     <li><a href="Solutions.html#RI">Business Intelligence</a></li>
     <li><a href="Solutions.html#Integrations">Integrations</a></li>
     <li><a href="Solutions.html#DM">Data Management</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
                        <li><a href="Customers.html">Our Customers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Support.html">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean that they're not clickable? I pasted this into a jsfiddle and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, in mobile view it's not clickable??

Comment: Maybe you can post a jsfiddle or codepen or something where the problem occurs

Comment: Okay how do i do that? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can go to jsfiddle.net, choose Bootstrap for a boilerplate, and paste your html there, then post the link to it. Or you can edit your post to put the code in a runnable snippet right in the post

Comment: https://codepen.io/melenthab/pen/zjWPJg

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have just checked your jsfiddle and it is working. Menu icon is not visible as fontawesome CSS is not included in Codepen.  is used for bar icon in font-awesome.
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

Also found some HTML issues as "!Doctype>" was visible on top. Try validating your template HTML using below validation tool.

http://validator.w3.org/